# Programa no se ejecuta correctamente

Tags: python, python-3.7, compilar, exe

Estaba haciendo una app pero cuando quiero compilarla no funciona, solo me aparece la ventana de comandos y se cierra, pero no abre el programa.
El codigo lo hize en spyder 5.0.2
Probé instalando Python 3.7.9 (qué es la versión con la que trabaja el programa spider), pero aún así no sirvieron los comandos para compilarla

ME ENTERÉ DE ALGO
Cuando pego la imagen importada si me abre, hay alguna forma de pegar la imagen en el programa o algo así?

También me sale un error en la consola

```
Reloaded modules: ipykernel, ipykernel._version, ipykernel.connect, ipykernel.kernelapp, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, ipython_genutils.importstring, ipykernel.iostream, jupyter_client.session, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, ipykernel.heartbeat, ipykernel.ipkernel, IPython.utils.tokenutil, ipykernel.comm, ipykernel.comm.manager, ipykernel.comm.comm, ipykernel.kernelbase, tornado.queues, tornado.locks, ipykernel.jsonutil, ipykernel.zmqshell, IPython.core.payloadpage, ipykernel.displayhook, ipykernel.datapub, ipykernel.serialize, ipykernel.pickleutil, ipykernel.codeutil, ipykernel.eventloops, ipykernel.parentpoller, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model, PIL.PngImagePlugin, PIL.ImageChops, PIL.ImageFile, PIL.ImagePalette, PIL.GimpGradientFile, PIL.GimpPaletteFile, PIL.ImageColor, PIL.PaletteFile, PIL.ImageSequence, pyparsing, cycler, kiwisolver, dateutil.rrule, win32api, win32security, ntsecuritycon, IPython.core.completerlib, storemagic, autoreload, matplotlib_inline, matplotlib_inline.backend_inline, matplotlib_inline.config, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axis3d, spyder, spyder.pil_patch
```

pensaba que a lo mejor me equivoque en alguna linea o algo (aunque la verdad el programa corre bastante bien en spider al menos)

```
import tkinter as tk


def traducir():
    trap = trad.get()
    resul.set(trap)
    
    frase = resul.get()
    traduccio=frase.replace('θЧ','j')
    traduccion=traduccio.replace('θφ','w')
    traduccionn=traduccion.replace('ЧѦ','ñ')
    puntos=traduccionn.replace('¯','. ')
    espacios=puntos.replace('˜',' ')

    
    entrada="æ&ødêτЧθëυγѦœρƸηжΩõφ§×λ¯"
    salida="abcdefghilmnopqrstuvxyz."
    letras=espacios.maketrans(entrada,salida)
    print(espacios.translate(letras))
    # print(resul.get().translate(letras))
    resul.set(espacios.translate(letras))
    
# frase=input("Escribe la palabra a traducir: ")

# traduccio=frase.replace('θЧ','j')

# traduccion=traduccio.replace('θφ','w')

# traduccionn=traduccion.replace('ЧѦ','ñ')

# espacios=traduccionn.replace('˜',' ')

# entrada="æ&ødêτЧθëυγѦœρƸηжΩõφ§×λ¯"
# salida="abcdefghilmnopqrstuvxyz."

# cambio=espacios.maketrans(entrada,salida)

# print("^"+espacios.translate(cambio))

ventana=tk.Tk()
trad = tk.StringVar()
resul = tk.StringVar()

ventana.title("Traductor.2")
ventana.resizable(0,0)
ventana.geometry('500x500')

image=tk.PhotoImage(file="Sin título-1.gif")
image=image.subsample(1,1)
label=tk.Label(image=image)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)
label.pack()

traduccion = tk.Label(ventana,textvariable=resul,wraplength=360,anchor="n")
traduccion.config(bg="#022C48", fg="#E59866",font=("Verdana",10,"bold","italic"),width=45, height=15)
traduccion.place(x=40,y=210)


caja = tk.Entry(ventana,width=50,textvariable=trad)
caja.place(x=100,y=150)

boton = tk.Button(ventana,text="Traducir",font=("Verdana",13),command=traducir,bg="#AED6F1",fg="#21618C")
boton.config(bg="white", fg="black")
boton.place(x=203,y=22)



ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dado que python es un lenguaje interpretado, realmente no se específicamente a qué te refieres cuando hablas de _compilar_.  Creo que vendría bien que incluyas etiquetas o explicaciones para que tu pregunta sea mejor entendida.

Answer (score 1):

El problema por el cual tu programa no se ejecuta es que necesita todos los archivos de los cuales depende para su funcionamiento. Con toda seguridad no haz puesto ningún control en el caso de que no se halle la imagen que deseas importar, por lo tanto si quitas la imagen del directorio tampoco el script funcionaría. Las soluciones son varias:

1. Controla el caso en el que no se encuentre la imagen con un `if` y cuando "compiles" (conviertas en .exe) tu script, colócalo en una carpeta junto con todos los archivos que necesita.
2. Si lo que buscas es tener todo dentro de un archivo .exe, entonces convierte la imagen en base64 e insértala en una variable de tu código o en tu base de datos (si la aplicación utiliza una).

En estos repositorios puedes encontrar un ejemplo de [cómo usar base64 en Tkinter](https://github.com/Ariel-MN/Tkinter_base64_Images) y [cómo convertir imágenes en base64 usando Python](https://github.com/Ariel-MN/Image_inside_Script/blob/master/base64_pillow_convert-file.py).